# Why was my question put on hold and can it be pushed to the front page now I edited it?

Tags: discussion, support

My question https://stackoverflow.com/q/17324793/1590323 was put on hold almost instantly after asking it. I edited it now in the hope it would be reopened but it looks like it didn't even appear on the front page due to the downvotes.

Can it be pushed to the fron page again so people can consider reopening it?

And why was it put on hold, exactly? There is a discussion in the comments but I still don't really understand. The 'on hold' message says I haven't done enough research effort, but I tried to, but didn't find anything.

Comment: 5 people who voted to close the question all gave the same reason. That reason should be indication enough as to *why* it was closed. Also, on hold questions are not bumped.

Comment: By virtue of the fact that you have edited the post it will appear in the Re-open queue. It'll be seen.

Comment: @Hiroto Well that's pretty stupid because nobody can see the edited question and eventually reopen it

Comment: @AlEverett Oh I didn't know about the re-open queue

Comment: @com.BOY it isn't stupid. it goes into a review queue, but still wont be re-opened in its current state; the whole "I have a usb scanner; how do i read input" is far too broad to ever hope of answering your specific case

Comment: @com.BOY You should read this if you want to understand better how "on hold" works http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1

Comment: `"I haven't done enough research effort but I don't have any clue about how I should do it."`  If you don't even know how to do basic research then you're a long way off from the point where you should be asking an SO question.  It's not in this site's scope to teach you how to do basic research, nor is it within the site's scope to do work for you when you haven't done the basic research yourself.  You'll need to use some other resource (perhaps taking some programming classes, reading books, etc.) to get enough of a basic understanding to be able to do simple research into a subject.

Comment: @Servy With 'how to do it' I reffered to the problem. I tried to do research, but didn't find anything, that's what I meant. That sentence is incorrect, you are right. Editing it now

Comment: @com.BOY The comments for that question would indicate that this is a fairly easy to research topic, to the point that a simple Google search on the keywords of your question provide the answers you're looking for.  That would indicate that you *didn't* really put in enough research effort.  Also note you should be *demonstrating* your research in the question.  Explain what you've done, what you've looked into, why that didn't solve your problem, etc.  It sounds like you did one Google search and gave up.  That's not really enough; you should be, at a bare minimum, doing a number of searches.

Comment: @AlEverett - the question [already went through the Re-open queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2398421#./2398421?&_suid=137234870851705659312960259295), and didn't fare very well there either.

Answer (score 12):

First, being on hold does not keep a question off the front page. Having a lot of downvotes will, but at net -4 yours should still appear. It's just that there is an enormous volume on SO so you don't stay on the front page long.

Second, nobody can push your question to the front page. Since you edited it, it has been put into a re-open queue, where people **might** vote to re-open.

However, I would not vote to re-open at the moment and I doubt others would either. It's still not a good quuestion. You know what you want to do, but have no clue how to start, and are rejecting some possibilities because they might not work. That's not a good SO question.

A good SO question would be more like "I am trying to X. I found this library Y, and I started trying to write my routine, [include 10-20 lines of code], but I can't figure out how to detect Z. How do I do that?" You are still at "are there any libraries to X?" SO isn't good at that.